# How to get descriptions for HRESULT error codes for WinRT / Windows 10 Store code?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I'm converting my Win32 app to UWP and am now writing Windows Store integration code using [Windows.Services.Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.store.aspx) namespace. For Win32 C++ it is mostly implemented via COM interface methods that seem to return their failures via `HRESULT` error codes.

So I thought that it would be nice to convert those `HRESULT` codes into descriptions that can be displayed for end-users.

I tried the following method:

```
int nOSError = (int)hresult;

LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
if(FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL,
    nOSError,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL))
{
    //Success

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't always work. For instance, `FormatMessage` returns `FALSE` and error code `ERROR_MR_MID_NOT_FOUND` for the following `HRESULT` values that I got experimentally from running my Windows Store integration code:

- `0x80072EFF`
- `0x803F6107`

Do you have any idea how to get descriptions for most `HRESULT` codes that are now used in Windows 10?

**EDIT:** Following what was suggested by [Sunius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1289007/sunius) below I came up with the following code to retrieve descriptions for WinRT error codes:

```
HRESULT hr;

ComPtr<IRestrictedErrorInfo> pErrInfo;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr = ::GetRestrictedErrorInfo(&pErrInfo)) &&
    pErrInfo)
{
    HRESULT hrErr;
    CComBSTR strErrDesc, strErrRestr, strSid;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pErrInfo->GetErrorDetails(&strErrDesc, &hrErr, &strErrRestr, &strSid)))
    {
        //Set empty message
        ::RoOriginateError(-1, NULL);

        //Get empty error message text
        ComPtr<IRestrictedErrorInfo> pEmptyErrInfo;
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = ::GetRestrictedErrorInfo(&pEmptyErrInfo)) &&
            pEmptyErrInfo)
        {
            HRESULT hrDummy;
            CComBSTR strEmptyErrDesc, strDummy1, strDummy2;
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pEmptyErrInfo->GetErrorDetails(&strEmptyErrDesc, &hrDummy, &strDummy1, &strDummy2)))
            {
                //Remove "The text associated with this error code could not be found" messages
                if (strErrDesc.ByteLength() == strEmptyErrDesc.ByteLength() &&
                    memcmp(strErrDesc.operator LPWSTR(), strEmptyErrDesc.operator LPWSTR(), strErrDesc.ByteLength()) == 0)
                {
                    strErrDesc.Empty();
                }

                if (strErrRestr.ByteLength() == strEmptyErrDesc.ByteLength() &&
                    memcmp(strErrRestr.operator LPWSTR(), strEmptyErrDesc.operator LPWSTR(), strErrRestr.ByteLength()) == 0)
                {
                    strErrRestr.Empty();
                }
            }
        }


        LPCTSTR pS_ErrDesc = strErrDesc.operator LPWSTR();
        LPCTSTR pS_Restr = strErrRestr.operator LPWSTR();

        TCHAR buff[1024];
        if(SUCCEEDED(::StringCchPrintf(buff,
            1024,
            L"ERROR hr=0x%X\n"
            L"desc=\"%s\"\n"
            L"restr=\"%s\""
            ,
            hrErr,
            pS_ErrDesc,
            pS_Restr
            )))
        {
            //Get message in 'buff'

        }
    }
    else
        ASSERT(NULL);
}
else
    ASSERT(NULL);
```

Comment: If you google the latter code you find it has something to do with licensing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, I did google them. What I'm asking about is a general case.

Comment: As I recall there is an `IErrorInfo` interface. I may remember the name incorrectly.

Comment: This page can sometimes help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx  You can usually get the component.

Comment: You are in the lap of the gods here. If the component author is on your side you can get a message but often it's just a code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HRESULTs on windows runtime APIs work similar to [SetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627(v=vs.85).aspx)/[GetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) mechanism, except that rather than storing the error code in the thread local storage, these APIs instead return the error code directly and store extended error information in thread local storage. Call [GetRestrictedErrorInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj219013(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve [IRestrictedErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224587(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, and then call [GetErrorDetails()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224588(v=vs.85).aspx) on it to get the error string.

Be careful when using this - you must not call any Windows Runtime APIs between receiving failed HRESULT and retrieving the IRestrictedErrorInfo interface, as it can be overwritten at any time (the same limitation exists with GetLastError(). There are two functions to set restricted error info: [RoOriginateLanguageException()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302172(v=vs.85).aspx) and [RoOriginateError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224651(v=vs.85).aspx).

I don't recommend using FormatMessage() unless you're using it as fallback when there's no IRestrictedErrorInfo available: in most cases, you will not get a reasonable message from it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this. I'll try it tomorrow. Just from curiosity though, what is `restrictedDescription` in [IRestrictedErrorInfo::GetErrorDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224588(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I have no idea :). Our code just concatenates both strings returned by GetErrorDetails.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show it in code though, how you'd deal with the results returned by `GetErrorDetails`? Unfortunately I can't emulate those error codes that I posted in my original message (they were genuine store error codes that I was getting when it was evidently down) so now to get something I disconnected network cable, for which I got `error` set as `0x80072EE7`, `description` as `The text associated with this error code could not be found`, and `restrictedDescription` as `The server name or address could not be resolved`.

Comment: That last one is exactly what I'd get from calling `FormatMessage` on that error code using `kernel32.dll` module as a parameter. So I'm curious, how do you eliminate superfluous/silly output, like the contents of the `description` field that I posted above?

Comment: We don't... unfortunately. It's as good at it gets. Even CLR does it that way for retrieving error message for its exception: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/26413145abcbdd49468db230a6f29784494f6f46/src/System.Private.Interop/src/WinRT/ExceptionHelpers.cs#L780

Comment: I posted a code snippet that I came up with using your suggestions. (It's an edit in my original post.) Would that be a sufficient way to retrieve an error description from a store app Win32 code?

Answer (score 3):

MSDN describes the general format of `HRESULT`:

[Structure of COM Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088.aspx)

And how to break up an `HRESULT` into its constituent component values:

[Using Macros for Error Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691242.aspx)

Under the described format:

- `0x80072EFF` is a failure code with a facility of `FACILITY_WIN32` (7) and an scode of 12031.  `FACILITY_WIN32` represents a Win32 error code wrapped in an `HRESULT`. Such values are created using the [`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746.aspx) macro. Win32 error codes in the 12000-12175 range are reserved for [Internet Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465.aspx). In this case, Win32 error code 12031 is `ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET` ("The connection with the server has been reset").
- `0x803F6107` is a failure code with a facility of `FACILITY_WINDOWS_STORE` (63) and an scode of 24839, which does not seem to be publicly defined, but may be related application licencing issues.

When using `FormatMessage()` to retrieve the text description of an `HRESULT`, you *usually* need to enable the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` flag and set the `lpSource` parameter to an `HMODULE` of a library that defines the error code.  However, in the cast of `FACILITY_WIN32`, most Win32 error codes can be retrieved using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` flag.

Other error codes tend to be library-defined instead, so you have to track down which library belongs to which facility, and then load that library so you can pass it to `FormatMessage()`.

In the case of Internet errors, they are defined in `WinInet.dll`, as described in WinInet's [Handling Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383884.aspx) documentation:

> To get the error text for an [Internet] error, call the FormatMessage function, passing it an HMODULE handle to Wininet.dll, which can be obtained using the GetModuleHandle function.

MSDN's documentation about [System Error Codes (12000-15999)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384.aspx) seems to contradict this (unless `FormatMessage()` handles this internally for you, which would not follow the WinInet documentation):

> The following list describes system error codes (errors 12000 to 15999). They are returned by the GetLastError function when many functions fail. To retrieve the description text for the error in your application, use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag.

In the case of `FACILITY_ITF` (4) errors, the `HRESULT` is interface-defined, so you can't use `FormatMessage()` at all.  But you might be able to use [`GetErrorInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032.aspx) instead, particularly if the implementing object supports the [`ISupportErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221083.aspx) interface.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what format `WinInet.dll` stores those error code descriptions in? I just loaded it into VS and it seems like the resource with type `11` holds them all. But it seems to have some binary format to it.

Comment: I got an [answer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14444/Enumerating-Message-Table-Contents) to my question in the note above, and even wrote a small app to search for an error code in the system folder using `message table` structure. So I found definition for `0x80072EFF` in `kernel32.dll` on my Windows 10 but so far not for `0x803F6107`. I guess I need to step into subfolders recursively from `C:\Windows\System32`. But this creates another issue -- it may take a long time to do this recursive search...

Comment: @c00000fd resource type 11 is `RT_MESSAGETABLE`. The format for [Message Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680357.aspx) are described on MSDN.

Comment: @c00000fd like I said, error codes are library-specific based on facility. I don't know the specific library that defines the `FACILITY_WINDOWS_STORE` error codes, but once you find it you will know the specific library and can hard-code it, you won't need to search for it each time.